# Cannot access data in Vue.js + Framework7

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, html-framework-7

I am new to Vue.js - right now I am playing with Framework7 + vue.js using Simple template (you can get it here:
https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7-Vue-Simple-Template)

The template has index.html with:

```
 <template id="page-about">
     <f7-page>
       <f7-navbar title="Page Abut" back-link="Go Back" sliding></f7-navbar>
       <f7-block inner>
           {{ testing }}
       </f7-block>
     </f7-page>   
</template>
```

Component is defined in app.js:

```
Vue.use(Framework7Vue)

Vue.component('page-about', {
  template: '#page-about',
  data: function() {
    return
    {
      testing: 'xxx'
    }
  }
})
```

Problem is that when I try to open this template I get "ReferenceError: testing is not defined"

Any idea what is causing it?

Comment: Is the `page-about` template possibly nested inside your Vue template?

Comment: It looks like you are using framework7 which will be initializing a bunch of components and routes. So the f7-page component won't have access to its parent's data unless you pass it in somehow. If you're just learning Vue, you are better off starting without a big framework that's complicating everything.

Comment: it seems it is inside <div id="app"> which is defined in Vue initialization as root: '#app'

Comment: try this way then, data: { testing : 'xxx'}